# Oracle - How to configure Oracle 21c XE for SSL traffic encryption?

Tags: oracle, oracle21c

I am new to Oracle and I am trying to configure an Oracle 21c XE database ([built from the official Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/21.3.0)) to encrypt traffic using SSL/TLS (just for encryption, not for mutual authentication). My configuration files are:

/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/XE/listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

# Extra configuration to enable SSL

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = /opt/my_wallet/)
    )
  )
```

/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/XE/sqlnet.ora

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT, HOSTNAME)

# Extra configuration to enable SSL

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = /opt/my_wallet/)
    )
  )
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
```

/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/XE/tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SID = PLSExtProc)
       (PRESENTATION = RO)
     )
  )
```

I also added a self-signed certificate to the wallet referenced in the configuration files.

When trying to connect with `sqlplus system/<password>@XE` it returns `ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.`

I have tried making different changes to the previous configuration, but I am always getting the same error. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.